# The new action/submit buttons

Tags: discussion, design

IMHO, the new blackish action/submit buttons don't fit into the overall design of the page at all. For me they feel like a fist on the eye (as we say in the German language room). They have this very dark, monochrome, 3Dish look while the rest of the site is light, colourful and exceptionally non-3D. Is there a good reason behind this? It seems quite like a step back from what we had before, from a graphic design point of view.

Answer (score 0):

How about to select a color that is the same harmony wheel with the rest ? I Check the link color is the opposite of the main SO color, so the button can be ether the same as the link, or the near darkest one as:

[image]

and how is look with many buttons together:
[image]

and one more on the link colors:

[image]

This is just an idea, do not take it as suggestion or anything. Totally personal, just "play" with the design.

Comment: And if we keep going, we can have one type of element for every colour - unicorns everywhere!

Comment: @J.Steen The elements are grouped into categories of action, and each category have a style. In same cases (like windows 8 now) there are elements for every color. Here how ever there is no need for that. Now if you won to place a color - then what this color can be ? and here is my idea, ether the blur of the link, ether the near darkest. The unicorns is not an argument :) after all is just an opinion.

Comment: I was being silly.

Comment: @J.Steen Do not worry, I am cool too :)

Comment: The buttons were designed to unify the UI elements across *all* Stack Exchange sites. The style does not just apply to Stack Overflow and choosing a color based on Stack Overflow's design wouldn't work. The old buttons were grey anyways, and I think a colored button would be *even more* annoying than the black ones, which I happen to think look quite nice.

Comment: @animuson I really not suggest anything, just "play" here :) - and I do not see that, each site have their style, or not ?

Comment: @animuson by the way, you say that the black is look quite nice, at the same time you implying that are annoying, and the color one will even more annoying. Well if they are base on harmony with the rest they will be not :)